# How to call overloaded operator+ and * depending on subclass in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, polymorphism, operator-overloading

I have an abstract class 'Block' with 3 subclasses BlockA/B/C.
BlockC has an attribute which is an array of 'Block's so that I can mix all 3 sub-Blocks in there (the possibilty for recursion by putting BlockC is desired if you're wondering).

I now want to multiply or add the contents of the array like it's done in the example function 1 but I just can't wrap my head around how to implement this with the operator+/*. Do I need to make them template functions?

```
class Block{};
class BlockA : public Block {};
class BlockB : public Block {};
class BlockC : public Block {
    Block array[2][2];
    
    void function1(){ Block result = array[0][0] + array [0][1]; }
};
```

Comment: What you are looking for is called [double dispatch](https://dzone.com/articles/double-dispatch-in-c).  I consider needing double dispatch to be a code smell, and probably a [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) violation.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this! Is there anything you would/could recommend to change about my approach to avoid using double dispatch? You're probably right about the code smell there... I suppose this is too short of a code snippet though.

Comment: Also, note that your array in BlockC cannot actually hold objects of type other than Block. You have to use an array of pointers in order to do that. As it is, if you assign a BlockC object to an element of the array, the non-Block parts are simply 'sliced' off.

Comment: The code is too short for me to extrapolate alternatives.  (Also, ditto with what Soronel mentioned.)  Note that a *code smell* is not sufficient to determine if the code is "bad", just needs a little extra scrutiny.  Sometimes a double dispatch solution is the right solution.

Comment: No worries, the actual array does store pointers, I just shortened it too much on that part. I'll watch out if this is the best solution then, thanks again!